# How to get dropdown selected value to contoller class with ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this html markup :

```
<p>
    Find by Column :
    @using (Html.BeginForm("getSelectedValue", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }))
    {

        @Html.DropDownList("ddlFilterColumns", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Column", Value = "1", Selected=true},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Alias", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Department Name", Value = "3"}
        }, "") 
    <span> Search :</span> @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
          <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
```

and this is my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
public string getSelectedValue()
{
    // this will get selected value
    var selectedValue = Request.Form["ddlFilterColumns"].ToString(); 
    return selectedValue;
}
```

When page redirects to department page then I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest.get_Form()
>
> EF_Crud_Samples.Controllers.DepartmentsController.getSelectedValue() in DepartmentsController.cs
> var selectedValue = Request.Form["ddlFilterColumns"].ToString();
>
> EF_Crud_Samples.Controllers.DepartmentsController.SortDepartmentData(List depts, string sortField, string currentSortField, string currentSortOrder) in DepartmentsController.cs
>
> - switch(getSelectedValue().ToString())
>   EF_Crud_Samples.Controllers.DepartmentsController.Index(string sortField, string currentSortField, string currentSortOrder, string currentFilter, string SearchString, Nullable pageNo) in DepartmentsController.cs

Please help me out of this situation.

Comment: Hi,where is your redirect to page code? You just return selectedValue.

Comment: @Rena here i just only need selectedValue from dropdownlist which stays in Department(folder)>>Index(page) to DepartmentController.

Comment: @Shalin Gajjar: The second parameter in `Html.BeginForm("getSelectedValue", "Index", FormMethod.Post, ...` is your controller name ("Index")?

Comment: no its DepartmentsController

Comment: @ShalinGajjar: The helper method in you case has the following format: `public static MvcForm BeginForm(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string actionName, string controllerName, FormMethod method, object htmlAttributes);` Therefore, the the second parameter is the **_controllerName_**. I just replaced the `Index` by controller name and your code is working for me.

Comment: Hi @Shalin Gajjar, could you pls share your code which can reproduce your issue? By using your such code, it can work well and give the selectedvalue.

Comment: Hi @ShalinGajjar, assume that you call `getSelectedValue` method in other action?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another page with value , you should change your `getSelectedValue` code , Here is simple demo:

```
     <p>
        Find by Column :
        @using (Html.BeginForm("getSelectedValue", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }))
        {
    
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlFilterColumns", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Column", Value = "1", Selected=true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Alias", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Department Name", Value = "3"}
            }, "") 
        <span> Search :</span> @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
              <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        }
    </p>
```

**Home/getSelectedValue**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult getSelectedValue()
    {
        // this will get selected value
        var selectedValue = Request.Form["ddlFilterColumns"].ToString();
        //redirect to index page
        return RedirectToAction("Index",new {value=selectedValue});
    }
```

**Home/Index**

```
       public IActionResult Index(string value)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

[image]